# Symfony2 - embedded form not getting displayed

Tags: php, symfony

I have  3 entities orders entity, product entity and orderProducts entity which has all the  ordered products. So basically the mapping for orderProducts is one order can have many products. I want to embed  orderProducts form into orders.
The problem I’m facing is the embedded form is not displayed.

Order Entity:

```
class Orders
   {  ...
      /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="order_date", type="datetime")
 */
private $orderDate;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Recipient", inversedBy="orders", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $recipientId;


...

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProducts", mappedBy="orders")
 */
private $orderProducts;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->orderProducts = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set orderDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $orderDate
 * @return Orders
 */
public function setOrderDate($orderDate)
{
    $this->orderDate = $orderDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get orderDate
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */
public function getOrderDate()
{
    return $this->orderDate;
}

/**
 * Set recipientId
 *
 * @param guid $recipientId
 * @return Orders
 */
public function setRecipientId($recipientId)
{
    $this->recipientId = $recipientId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get recipientId
 *
 * @return guid 
 */
public function getRecipientId()
{
    return $this->recipientId;
}

....
/**
 * Set orderProducts
 *
 * @param \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts
 * @return Orders
 */
public function setOrderProducts(\Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts = null)
{
    $this->orderProducts = $orderProducts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get orderProducts
 *
 * @return \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts 
 */
public function getOrderProducts()
{
    return $this->orderProducts;
}

/**
 * Add orderProducts
 *
 * @param \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts
 * @return Orders
 */
public function addOrderProduct(\Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts)
{
    $this->orderProducts[] = $orderProducts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove orderProducts
 *
 * @param \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts
 */
public function removeOrderProduct(\Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts)
{
    $this->orderProducts->removeElement($orderProducts);
}
```

}

Product Entity

```
class Product
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

...

/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OrderProducts", mappedBy="product")
 */
private $orderProducts;

...
public function __construct()
{
    $this->orderProducts = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
...

/**
 * Add orderProducts
 *
 * @param \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts
 * @return Product
 */
public function addOrderProduct(\Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts)
{
    $this->orderProducts[] = $orderProducts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove orderProducts
 *
 * @param \Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts
 */
public function removeOrderProduct(\Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts $orderProducts)
{
    $this->orderProducts->removeElement($orderProducts);
}

/**
 * Get orderProducts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getOrderProducts()
{
    return $this->orderProducts;
}
}
```

orderProducts Entity

```
class OrderProducts
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Orders", inversedBy="order_products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="order_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $orders;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="order_products")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $product;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $quantity;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set order
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrders(Orders $orders)
{
    $this->orders = $orders;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get order
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->orders;
}

/**
 * Set product
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setProduct(Product $product)
{
    $this->product = $product;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get product
 *
 * @return mixed 
 */
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->product;
}
/**
 * Set quantity
 *
 * @param string $quantity
 * @return OrderProducts
 */
public function setQuantity($quantity)
{
    $this->quantity = $quantity;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get quantity
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getQuantity()
{
    return $this->quantity;
}
```

}

OrdersType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('orderDate', 'date', array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin:10px;width:200px;height:25px;display:inline-block;')))
        ->add('recipientId', new RecipientType())
        ->add('orderProducts', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new OrderProductsType(),
                'options' => array('label' => false),
                'cascade_validation' => true,
                'allow_add' => true        
        ))
        //->add('orderProducts', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => OrderProductsType::class))

    ;

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\Orders'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'orders';
}
```

OrderProductsType.php

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('product', 'entity', array('label' => 'Product ','attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin:10px;width:200px;height:25px;display:inline-block;'),
                'class' => 'InventorySystemBundle:Product',
                'choice_label' => 'product_name',
            ) )
        ->add('quantity', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin:10px;width:200px;height:25px;display:inline-block;')))

    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Inventory\SystemBundle\Entity\OrderProducts'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'orderproducts';
}
```

createAction from OrdersController.php

```
 public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $order = new Orders();
    $orderProducts = new OrderProducts();
    $order->addOrderProduct($orderProducts);
    $request_all = $request->request->all();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($order);
    try {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "failed : ".$e->getMessage();
    }

    $recipientId = $request_all['inventory_systembundle_orders']['recipientId'];
    $productId = $request_all['inventory_systembundle_orders']['product'];
    $quantity = $request_all['inventory_systembundle_orders']['quantity'];

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush();

        $product = $em->getRepository('InventorySystemBundle:Product')->find($productId);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $orderProducts->setProduct($product);
        $orderProducts->setOrders($order);
        $orderProducts->setQuantity($quantity);
        $em->persist($orderProducts);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('orders_new'));
    }

    return array(
        'order' => $order,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

I’m not sure what i am missing out. I’m not sure whether I’m going wrong with the associations.  Can someone please help me with this?

twig file

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
<div align="right">
    <a href="{{ path('orders') }}">
        Back to the list
    </a>
</div>
  <h1>Orders creation</h1>
  <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form(form) }} 
    {{ form_end(form) }}  
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think we'll need the view file that you are rendering your form in... I don't see it here.

Comment: I have added the twig file

Comment: The problem is in the view file, form(form) does not render the nested form.You are probably getting a label only right?

Comment: yes I get only the label of orderProducts form

Comment: Do you think it has anything to do with the associations in the entity? I mean if the mapping has gone wrong or something....

Comment: No, that part is just a display issue in twig. I am still looking up ways to fix it... I have a hackish way of doing it myself, that is why I didn't write it as an answer.

Comment: write the following under form_start(form) but before form(form):
{%for orderProduct in form.orderProducts%}
{{form_row(orderProduct.quantity)}}
{{form_row(orderProduct.product)}}
{%endfor%}
{# you will have to customize your display once data shows#}

Comment: I tried using your solution but that did not work, infact, I had tried this earlier also.

Comment: A new entity has no orderProducts yet, try with manually inserting into the database. I realize it would not be a full solution but it would be steps forward.

Comment: Actually if I add orderProducts inputs directly in orders form the submit works correctly. The data is saved in the respective tables. But I just wanted to know why it does not work by embeded forms

Comment: I wanted it to be a separate form

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some JavaScript code to render the collection (your **orderProducts** form)

Check out the symfony documentation for that, it's easy enough.
[Symfony Doc - Embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html)